# Reverb Algoritms

Tags: reverb, algorithmic

Looking at designing some effective reverb in SuperCollider, wondering is anyone can point me in the direction of some good resources for algorithms?

Answer (score 2):

Checkout this [page](http://freeverb3vst.osdn.jp/reverb.shtml).

If you want go deeper try [this one](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/Reverb/Reverb.pdf) from J. Smith

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13054)

Comment: @audionuma while I agree some more details would be helpful.  The question is actually asking for resources about algorithms, so the links themselves are technically the answer.  (I actually missed this at first as well, but noticed it when I revisited the question later.)